# battery gets drained at a certain time

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, samsung-galaxy-s-4, battery

Lately I've gotten a very strange behavior from my phone:

at a certain time (around 23h) the battery begins to drain,

it's very annoying because I used to keep the phone on during the night (and as a result woke up with a dead phone in the morning).

I use juice plotter to see what's going on and surely:
at around 11 the graph drops at a higher speed compared to the graph during daytime.

I didn't install new apps (that I know of), don't use wifi or mobile network.

I do keep my phone updated (I regularly update all my apps) so an update of a certain app can be the cause (question is: which app?))

If I look at the info of the os itself it doesn't show a certain app using more battery then usual.

How can I investigate this issue?

S.

Comment: Have you tried changing your battery? try & tell us what will happen.

Comment: Look who's using cpu after the drain starts (like, look at live cpu usage)

Comment: Is it possible your wifi is trying to connect to a neighbor who turns his network on/off? Close proximity + password enabled + failure = continued attempts until drainage. In fact, I exploit this condition when my tablet freezes; I re-charge an empty battery which has unfrozen to get past it.

Comment: Concerning my previous suggestion - this is more likely to be evidenced if you are placing your phone in a different location overnight than before?

Comment: @wbogacz: hey, this is not the issue (I don't use wifi or mobile network)